# Drawing a grid using canvas

Tags: canvas

I want to create a grid with different inputs. The canvas should accept those inputs and create the grid.
For example 8*8 grid, 16*16 grid or 32*32 grid with the same height and width. But the grids are not displaying. Cannot i use if else statements in Canvas. Please help me.

```
//HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCss.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="pixelArt">
    <h2>PIXEL ART</h2>
<div class="canvasSec">
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="makeChanges">
<p>Pick Color</p>
<input id="pickColor" type="color"><br><br>

<label>Choose Grid</label>
<select id="gridSize">
    <option value="8*8">8*8</option>
    <option value="12*12">12*12</option>
    <option value="16*16">16*16</option>
    <option value="32*32">32*32</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
</html>


//js
    var pickColor = document.getElementById('pickColor');
var gridSize = document.getElementById('gridSize').value;
console.log(gridSize);

var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
function drawBoard(){
    debugger;
if(gridSize === 8*8){
    for(var x = 1; x < 400; x+=50){
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, 400);
    }
    for(var y = 1; y < 400; y+=50){
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(400, y);
    }
}else if(gridSize === 16*16){
    for(var x = 1; x < 400; x+=25){
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, 400);
    }
    for(var y = 1; y < 400; y+=25){
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(400, y);
    }
}

context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
context.stroke();
}
drawBoard();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are just having a bit of trouble with the math behind...
With `if else` statements your code will get very very long

Here is what I would do:

```js
var grid = {x:8, y:8}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawBoard() {
  w = canvas.width - 2
  for (var x = 1; x < canvas.width; x += w/grid.x) {
    context.moveTo(x, 0);
    context.lineTo(x, 400);
  }
  
  h = canvas.height - 2
  for (var y = 1; y < canvas.height; y += h/grid.y) {
    context.moveTo(0, y);
    context.lineTo(400, y);
  }
  context.stroke();
}


drawBoard();
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=160 height=160>
```

As you can see I'm using the `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to keep the grid size to math our canvas, but you can certainly change that to anything you like.
Hopefully, that gets you closer to your needs.